# What is the most efficient way to select a result based off of what a user types?

Tags: c++, string, user-input

I am currently working on a c++ project that requires me to allow the user to type in certain words, and does different things based off of the words typed.

For example, say the user types "thing1", it would then discuss one thing, and if the user types "thing2", it does something else, and if the user types "thing3" it does something different from the first two words, and if they don't type any of the previously mentioned words, it makes the user retype until one of the three words are selected.

As I currently work in c++, I found that using `std::string`s could allow the user to type in what they want. However, unlike using things like `int`s or other types of data, this would not be able to instantly go into switch statements, meaning that, as far as I know, one would have to either do an if else statement for each word that was chosen, which could be more efficient in the short term, could take up a lot more time and lines as you do repeat the same amount of selections (which could make it more inefficient as a lot of selections in my project takes 2-4 choices).

On the other hand, there is another way I found that I am currently doing for my project which while being somewhat inefficient in the short term, is a lot more efficient in the long run for the selections that take the same number of items.

As an example, if I want to make a program that looks for the user to type either “thing1”, “thing2”, or “thing3”, and then ask the program to look for “thing4”, “thing5”, or “thing6” and then “thing7”, “thing8” or “thing9”, while using the first method would be a lot of trouble, constantly using if else statements every time, the second works by making a function that takes the std::string, the list of accepted phrases, and then does the if else statements there, with each answer type corresponding to a int, which is then returned and put into a switch statement that print out the different results, allowing me to use the same if/else list multiple times, the second method just takes one set of if else statement in another function that turns the strings into an int, which is then returned in order allow it to be put in a switch statement.

The question I have is, are these the only way to allow a user to type in certain words and it do something based off of that in c++, or is there some third way that makes this kind of problem trivial? I am asking because one of the types of questions that I need to ask for my program can take 12-14 inputs, and doing that much if/else or case statements would likely be super annoying, so want to know if there is another way that takes less work.

1st way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::string things;
    std::cout << "type a thing" << endl;
    std::cin >> things;
    int redo = 0;
    do {
        redo = 0;
        if (things == "thing1") {
            std::cout << "computer do thing 1" << endl;
        }
        else if (things == "thing2") {
            std::cout << "thing 2 was done" << endl;
        }
        else if (things == "thing3") {
            std::cout << "completed thing 3" << endl;
        }
        else {
            redo = 1;
            std::cout << "please choose one of the things" << endl;
            std::cin >> things;
        }
    } while ((things != "thing1" && things != "thing2" && things != "things3") || redo == 1);
    std::string things2;
    std::cout << "type another thing" << endl;
    std::cin >> things2;
    int redone = 0;
        do {
            redone = 0;
            if (things2 == "thing4") {
                std::cout << "computer do thing 4" << endl;
            }
            else if (things2 == "thing5") {
                std::cout << "thing 5 was done" << endl;
            }
            else if (things2 == "thing6") {
                std::cout << "completed thing 6" << endl;
            }
            else {
                redo = 1;
                std::cout << "please choose one of the things" << endl;
                std::cin >> things;
            }
        } while ((things2 != "thing4" && things2 != "thing5" && things2 != "things6") || redo == 1);
    
}
```

2nd way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int converter(string listed, string first, string second, string third) {
    int returning;
    if(listed == first){
        returning = 1;
    }
    else if (listed == second) {
        returning = 2;
    }
    else if (listed == third) {
        returning = 3;
    }
    else {
        returning = 4;
    }
    return returning;
}
int main() {
    std::string things;
    std::cout << "type a thing" << endl;
    std::cin >> things;
    int switchCase = converter(things, "thing1", "thing2", "thing3");
    int redo = 0;
    do {
        redo = 0;
        switch (switchCase) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "computer do thing 1" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "thing 2 was done" << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "completed thing 3" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "please choose one of the things" << endl;;
            std::cin >> things;
            switchCase = converter(things, "thing1", "thing2", "thing3");
            break;
        }
    } while (switchCase==4 || redo == 1);
    std::string things2;
    std::cout << "type another thing" << endl;
    std::cin >> things2;
    int switchCase2 = converter(things2, "things4", "things5", "things6");
    int redone = 0;
    do {
        redone = 0;
        switch (switchCase2) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "computer do thing 4" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "thing 5 was done<< endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "completed thing 6" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "please choose one of the things" >> endl;
            std::cin >> things2;
            switchCase = converter(things, "thing4", "thing5", "thing6");
        }
    } while (switchCase2 == 4 || redo == 1);

}
```

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::string> allThingsToDo;`  -- The key in the map are the valid inputs, the data is the "thing to do" associated with the key.

Comment: Or a `std::map` with `std::string` as the key and `std::function` as the value.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you'll ever notice any performance difference from doing some string comparisons in an optimized build of a trivial application like this.

Comment: *I am asking because one of the types of questions that I need to ask for my program can take 12-14 inputs,* -- The general way to do this is to load a map with the valid data and do a `map::find` for the item that was inputted by the user.  Having endless if/else statements shouts out that this can be done using a map or similar type (std::map, std::unordered_map, etc.).

Comment: Also, as @JesperJuhl pointed out, performance is not an issue.  The real issue is code maintenance.

Comment: _@dragonlord_ as currently formulated, your question is merely opinion based, and hence _off-topic_ here.

Comment: A version using a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>>` to map a command to "something to do" could look like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/zdqTY6ojn)

Answer (score 1):

As a majority of the comments said, using maps is a thing that would help to greatly decrease the workload that I need to solve the problem at hand, although I honestly didn't really know that much about maps, if anything at all (as the tutorials that I used in order to learn about c++ didn't even discuss the concept). I should also give a shout out to @TedLyngmo, who showed a code to do the first part of the example of listing out Things 1-3, which I was able to look at to get somewhat of an understanding of how maps work by testing to see if the second part of the maps, the function<void()>, was like an actual fuction, with the ability to handle multiple lines of code and call other functions, or was just a single line thing. After confirming that the former was the case, I was able to easily replicate the example in full by adding onto the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>> things{
        {"thing1", [] { std::cout << "computer do thing 1\n"; }},
        {"thing2", [] { std::cout << "thing 2 was done\n"; }},
        {"thing3", [] { std::cout << "completed thing 3\n"; }},
    };
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>> things2{
        {"thing4", [] { std::cout << "computer do thing 4\n"; }},
        {"thing5", [] { std::cout << "thing 5 was done\n"; }},
        {"thing6", [] { std::cout << "completed thing 6\n"; }}
    };
    std::string thing;

    while (std::cout << "type a thing\n", std::getline(std::cin, thing)) {
        if (auto it = things.find(thing); it != things.end()) {
            it->second();
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << '"' << thing << "\" is not valid - please choose one of the things\n";
        }
    }
    std::string thing2;
    while (std::cout << "type a thing\n", std::getline(std::cin, thing2)) {
        if (auto it = things2.find(thing2); it != things2.end()) {
            it->second();
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << '"' << thing << "\" is not valid - please choose one of the things\n";
        }
    }
}
```